# core data fetching int not displaying on tableview cell

Tags: swift, core-data, integer, fetch, append

I am writing swift code with the goal of displaying a increasing number on every tableview cell. Right now the int is not being display. So the first tableview cell should say 1 and the 2nd should say 2. You can see in the gif below what is going along with the tableview cell and nothing is appearing in them when the button is clicked. The func below is when the button is clicked.

```
   var pageNumber = 1


 var itemName : [Player] = []

func enterData() {
    theScores.reloadData()
 
 let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 
 let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext
 
 // Simpler way to create a new Core Data object
 let theTitle = Player(context: context)

 // Simpler way to set the position attribute

    
    theTitle.positon = Int64(pageNumber)
    print(pageNumber)
 
    
    // pageNumber must be of type Int64, otherwise use Int64(pageNumber)
 
 do {
     try context.save()
     itemName.append(theTitle)
     pageNumber += 1
 } catch {
     // handle errors
 }
 
 

 }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
    let cell = theScores.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for : indexPath)
   
    cell.selectionStyle = .default

    let attr5 = title.value(forKey: "positon") as? String
    
    let text = [" Item :",   attr5].compactMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(text)"
    
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    
    
    return cell
    
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called? Often times when something isn't showing with table views its because the function isn't even being called because you forgot to do something like assign the table view's delegate to the view controller.

Comment: Why are you calling reloadData() at the start of the function, shouldn't that be at the end (or even better outside of the function)?

Comment: If your question is about why the table cells don’t show what you expect, you need to include the code that manages the table view. Your current sample code doesn’t seem to be relevant to your question or your image.

Comment: @TomHarrington added code that manages tableview

Comment: @Eric33187 added code that manages tableview

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint in your table view function that you added to make sure it's being called. If it isn't, check whether you forgot to assign your view controller as the table view's data source. If it did show, try next to just assign arbitrary text to the label to ensure that is working properly (e.g. `cell.textLabel?.text = "make sure this shows"`). Then report back.

Comment: Why are you typecasting an Int to a String, `let attr5 = title.value(forKey: "positon") as? String` (and why use `value(forKey:)` instead of accessing the property directly)? Access it as an Int and then create a string from it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you show me how to do what you are describing.

Comment: `"\(title.positon)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work. You have this:

```
let attr5 = title.value(forKey: "positon") as? String

let text = [" Item :",   attr5].compactMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
```

This is a really complicated way to try and do this, and it doesn't work as written. The problem is that the value of `position` is an `Int64` and you need a string. But using `as?` like that doesn't turn it into a string. When that line of code runs, Swift says, can I just make this into a string? But it can't. So the `as? String` is nil, and your table cells don't include the number because the conversion failed.

A better way would be something like

```
if let position = title.value(forKey: "positon") {
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Item : \(positon))"
}
```

But that's only if you really want to use `value(forKey:)` for some reason. You probably don't need that because normally Xcode creates a subclass of `NSManagedObject` for each entity with named properties. So even better would be

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Item: \(title.position)"
```

These both work because string interpolation knows how to convert an integer to a string.

Comment: I tried your code and it says it can't find position in scope. I added a photo above if that helps.

Comment: if you do it like this it works         if let position = title.value(forKey: "positon") {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Item : \(title.positon))"
        }
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Item: \(title.positon)"

Answer (score 0):

You probably should call .reloadData() after context.save()